# Ansible command always show SETUPTOOLS WILL STOP WORKING warning

Tags: python, ubuntu, ansible, setuptools

`ansible` command always print warning below:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/py2_warn.py:22: UserWarning: Setuptools will stop working on Python 2
************************************************************
You are running Setuptools on Python 2, which is no longer
supported and
>>> SETUPTOOLS WILL STOP WORKING <<<
in a subsequent release (no sooner than 2020-04-20).
Please ensure you are installing
Setuptools using pip 9.x or later or pin to `setuptools<45`
in your environment.
If you have done those things and are still encountering
this message, please comment in
https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/1458
about the steps that led to this unsupported combination.
************************************************************
  sys.version_info < (3,) and warnings.warn(pre + "*" * 60 + msg + "*" * 60)
```

system info: ubuntu 16.04

install method: apt-get install ansible

How can I get rid of this warnings?

TIPS: ansible seems to use `/usr/bin/python` which is `python2.7` default in ubuntu environment.

Answer (score 0):

### Quick and dirty way:

edit `/usr/bin/ansible`

add code:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
```

But is there a better way to make ansible use python3 environment?

### Better way

1. use `pyenv` or other tools to install python3
2. make sure run `/usr/bin/env python` runs python3
3. edit `/usr/bin/ansible`

`#!/usr/bin/python -> #!/usr/bin/env python`

4. use `pip install ansble` to install missing package.

otherwise `ansible module not found` error will show.